# How to use AWS EC2 instance as a vps remote computer? I want to connect using Teamviewer

Tags: amazon-web-services, ftp, putty, filezilla

I can connect to EC2 instance using Putty, Filezila and other FTP programs.
but I want to connect to AWS via Teamviewer.
Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Did you try it? Did it work?

Comment: I tried it and it is working, you can install xrdp and open 3389 port in network setting. and then you can connect to ec2 using rdp and turn on teamviewer.
https://linuxhint.com/install_xrdp_server_ubuntu/
follow this link..